# CLLocationManager not calling didUpdateLocation() in iOS 10.2 [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-location

So I wrote this piece of code a couple months ago (when iOS 10.1 was still the latest version), and it worked fine. However, when I tried recently with iOS 10.2, the `CLLocationManager` doesn't seem to call the `didUpdateLocation` function. When I reverted the simulator back to iOS 10.1 it worked again.

When I tried to look up my problem, all I got were solutions for the iOS 8 update, where you had to update your info.plist as well. Therefore, I was wondering if there is something extra that I need to do with CoreLocation for iOS 10.2. I have the `Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description` and `Privacy - Location Always Usage Description` information properties in the info.plist.

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var userLocation:CLLocation = CLLocation()

func handleSwitchChanged() {
    if onlineSwitch.isOn {
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != .authorizedAlways {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            onlineSwitch.isOn = false
            return
        }
        (mainScreen as! MainScreenController).currUser.isOnline = 1
        determineUserLocation()
    } else {
        (mainScreen as! MainScreenController).currUser.isOnline = 0
        removeFromFirebase()
    }
}

func determineUserLocation() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    userLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the `delegate`? I mean... calling `handleSwitchChanged()` which calls `determineUserLocation()`? Also, shouldn't `!= .authorizedAlways` be `!= .authorizedWhenInUse`?

Comment: @AlejandroIván I set the delegate in `determineUserLocation()`, which is called whenever a button is pressed. I think it is `.authorizedAlways`. I tried `.authorizedWhenInUse` and it didn't work.

Comment: Yes, but you're requesting a when in use authorization. It means it will never be always and, thus, it will always get into that "if" and then return. Try removing that return so your function gets to actually call determineUserLocation()

Comment: I request the always authorization somewhere else in the app. And looking at the value at that point in time, the `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()` is `.authorizedAlways`.

Comment: 1. Your issue is hard to reproduce, because we don't know when/where `handleSwitchChanged ` is called nor we if `onlineSwitch` is `true` or not. 2. Also did you enable locations in backgroundmodes? 3. other than that...your code looks fine but to be on the safe side wrap your `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` inside a main thread dispatch. You could be having run loop issues and that way your code would be ran on an active runloop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might just be an error with iOS 10.2. When I try the same code on 10.1 and 10.3, it works fine.